# How to add multiple javascript functions to an external file step by step

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, obfuscation, minify

So i have some javascript functions all around my website and i would like to organize them in one file.js

So i can call the file in the header like this:

```
<script src="myfunctions.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any build tool will do, though there are some that are more well-suited to JavaScript. A very dumb solution would be just to have a Makefile that uses "cat" to concatenate your scripts and then runs them through the closure compiler.

Comment: I understand that RequireJs and Grunt are currently popular ways of doing these sorts of things. As is Bower. I'm not familiar with these enough, yet, though to be able to make an intelligent recommendation.

Comment: I doubt poster knows that any of those things mean, hence my simple answer...

Comment: Also: require.js is an asynchronous module dependency loader, Grunt is a taskrunner, and Bower is a package manager. Those all do entirely different things...

Comment: Pretty clear zero research went into question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply cut and paste the contents between the `<script>` tags into `myfunctions.js`.

Comment: That seems like a bad way to organize code in the long run. Having separate, modular pieces of code is more maintainable.

Comment: He asked how to do something, so I told him how. This should not get a downvote. He will get exactly the functionality and usage he asked for. I'll take a wild guess and assume something like AMD is a little above the level this poster is learning at, given the nature of the question.

Comment: I did add the content between the <script> tags and call the file in my header like this <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mydomain.com/myfunctions.js"></script> and is not working at all.

Comment: Did you remove the original stuff between the tags? Did you make sure to omit the script tags themselves in the new file? Did you make sure to put the call to that file below any other dependencies?

Comment: @Oscar try putting the `<script src="...">` tag at the ***bottom*** of the HTML page, right above `</body>`. All of the `$("#el").doSomething();` functions only work if they're *below* `<div id="el">`.

Comment: Any suggestions ? Some examples putting the functions that i already wrote on the question in one file and calling them? Step by step.. I will appreciate it!

Comment: Most likely solution is what @Norguard said in his/her comment